# add library from Git to Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I know this must be a pretty basic question, but I'm new to `Android Studio` and `gradle`, and I can't find any up-to-date info on this.

I'm trying to add this library to my project: [android-segmented-control](https://github.com/hoang8f/android-segmented-control).

It doesn't look like I can add it to my `build.gradle` file (correct?). I'd like to do it that way, of course, and not download the project if possible.

If I do need to download the project, how do I link it up with my existing project? Again, I haven't been able to find anything that is current that describes this process for `Android Studio 0.5.3`

Comment: if you download a project and like to add it to your existing one then you could do that by adding it as a module. (Right click on project goto -> open module settings -> add your new project as a module).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks `@Thomas Bouron` for the hint !
I have pushed my library to maven center, so you just need to add the following dependency to your `build.gradle`.

```
dependencies {
    compile 'info.hoang8f:android-segmented:1.0.0'
}
```

(A little late for `@workInAFishBowl` but it may be helpful for others.).

Answer (score 2):

The library you mentioned does not seems to be pushed on maven central or any other maven repository. As this library contains resources files, **you cannot add it as a jar**.

The only way to use it is clone the git repository and **add it as a module to your android app project**.

Meanwhile, you can ask the author to make it available on a Maven repository like [OSS sonatype](https://oss.sonatype.org/#welcome)